# Property 'blur' does not exist on type 'TextInput'

Tags: typescript, react-native

How to use `useRef` with React Native [`TextInput`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) to have correct types?

React Native documentation says that [`TextInput`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) has 4 methods including [`blur`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#blur).

But, as you can see on the image below it shows me an error.

[image]

What type I must use?

Answer (score 0):

I imported `TextInput` from the `react-native-gesture-handler` instead of `react-native`

Instead of this

```js
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

should be this

```js
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
```